# Why does this c++ code work properly in Linux but not in Windows

Tags: c++, arrays, linux, windows

I am a c++ student that is stuck in a tight situation. I have code that seems like it would functionally work (well, the parts I have completed) but something in the memory allocation is screwing up in Windows 7, but not in my ancient laptop that runs ubuntu. Of course, the code is compiled and tested on Windows 7.

I will post the entire code so you can compile it and attempt to highlight the relevant bits that are jamming up. The code is designed to open a file, parse the file into a 2D array, and then use that array to fill a few others needed to find the maximum vales by year and so on.

Following the code is the text file used to populate the mainArray, referred to as "Energy.dat". If necessary I can also upload the .doc file to fully explain the purpose behind all of this. The gist is, the different columns in the file are different types of energy, with the column index corresponding to the values in the array "types[]". I need to sum multiple columns into the separate arrays "fossilArray", "renewableArray", and "totalArray". In which, in Windows 7, are getting occasionally filled with junk values (i.e. 4.3e206), and different values on different computers. Where this occurs is shown in the comments.

I have asked my professor and he believed it to be an operating system problem. Which appears to be true, but I lack the knowledge and understanding to fix it. Any input would be helpful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
//#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

void drawLine();
int returnMaxIndex(double mainArray[][14], int j);
int returnMaxIndex(double array[]);

int main()
{
    string yearString; char answer = '@'; char Eanswer = '@';   //initialize to a value to get inside while loop

    long int year = 1979;                   //same thing here

    int i, j;
    double temp;

    double mainArray[29][14];  //EVERY VALUE LOADS PERFECTLY
    double fossilArray[29];  //index 9, 12, 13 get junk values
    double renewableArray[29]; //also gets occasional junk values
    double totalArray[29];     //same here

    string types[14] = {"Year", "Coal", "Petroleum", "Natural Gas", "Other Gases", "Nuclear",
                            "Hydroelectric (pumped storage)", "Hydroelectric", "Biomass-Wood",
                             "Biomass-Other", "Geothermal", "Solar", "Wind", "Other"};

    ifstream file("Energy.dat");

    if(file.fail())
        return -1;

    for(i = 0; i < 29; i++)         //load main array
        for(j = 0; j < 14; j++)
            file >> mainArray[i][j];

    for(i = 0; i < 29; i++)         //load fossil sum array
        for(j = 1; j < 5; j++)
            fossilArray[i] += mainArray[i][j];

    for(i = 0; i < 29; i++)         //load renewable energy array
        for(j = 6; j < 13; j++)
            renewableArray[i] += mainArray[i][j];

    for(i = 0; i < 29; i++)         //load total energy array
        for(j = 1; j < 14; j++)
            totalArray[i] += mainArray[i][j];

//  for(int i = 0; i < 29; i++)
//  {   for(int j = 0; j < 14; j++)
//          {cout << fixed << setprecision(0) << setw(10) << mainArray[i][j] << " ";    if(j == 6) cout << endl;}
//      cout << endl << endl;}

//  for(i = 0; i < 29; i++)
        cout << setw(20) << std::right << fixed << fossilArray[12] << endl;

    cout << "A. Shows the energy output for a year you select between 1980 and 2008"<< endl
        << "B. Gives you the year in which each form of energy has its peak output" << endl
        << "C. Create an excel compatible output file for the total of a type of energy \n\tOR as a percentage by year" << endl;


    while (static_cast<int>(answer) < 65 || (static_cast<int>(answer) > 67 && static_cast<int>(answer) < 97) || static_cast<int>(answer) > 99)
    {
        cout << "Please choose an option A, B, or C: ";
        cin.get(answer);
    }
    drawLine();
    switch(answer)
    {
        case 'A': case 'a':
        {
            cout << "Enter the year in which you want to see the energy output(1980 - 2008): ";
            while(year < 1980 || year > 2008)
            {
                cout << endl;
                getline(cin, yearString);
                year = strtol(yearString.c_str(), NULL, 10);

            }

            drawLine();

            if(year == 1980) i = 0; if(year == 1981) i = 1; if(year == 1982) i = 2; if(year == 1983) i = 3; if (year == 1984) i = 4; if(year == 1985) i = 5;
            if(year == 1986) i = 6; if(year == 1987) i = 7; if(year == 1988) i = 8; if(year == 1989) i = 9; if (year == 1990) i = 10; if(year == 1991) i = 11;
            if(year == 1992) i = 12; if(year == 1993) i = 13; if(year == 1994) i = 14; if(year == 1995) i = 15; if (year == 1996) i = 16; if(year == 1997) i = 17;
            if(year == 1998) i = 18; if(year == 1999) i = 19; if(year == 2000) i = 20; if(year == 2001) i = 21; if (year == 2002) i = 22; if(year == 2003) i = 23;
            if(year == 2004) i = 24; if(year == 2005) i = 25; if (year == 2006) i = 26; if(year == 2007) i = 27; if(year == 2008) i = 28;

            cout << "The energy produced in the year " << year << " was...(in megawatt hours)   % of total" << endl;
            for (j = 1; j < 14; j++)
            {
                double temp = mainArray[i][j]; double temp2 = totalArray[i];
                cout << setw(36)<< std::left << types[j]  << fixed << setprecision(3) << std::right << setw(16) << mainArray[i][j] << "     " << setprecision(3) << (temp*1.0/temp2)*100.0 << endl;
                //(abs(mainArray[i][j]))/(totalArray[j])
            }
            drawLine();


        }break;

        case 'B': case 'b':
        {
            cout << "A. Coal  B. Petroleum  C. Natural Gas  D. Other Gas  E. Nuclear" << endl
                << "F. Hydro Pumped Storage  G. Hydroelectric  H. Biomass-wood" << endl;
                drawLine();
            cout << "I. Biomass-waste  J. Geothermal  K. Solar  L. Wind  M. Other energy" << endl
                <<"N. All fossil fuels  O. All renewable  P. Grand total" <<endl;
            drawLine();

            cout << "Enter the type of energy you want to see the the peak output year: ";
            while(static_cast<int>(Eanswer) < 65 || (static_cast<int>(Eanswer) > 80  && static_cast<int>(Eanswer) < 97) || static_cast<int>(Eanswer) > 112)
            {
                cin.get(Eanswer);
            }
            switch(Eanswer)
            {
                case 'A': case 'a': j = 1; break; case 'B': case 'b': j = 2; break; case 'C': case 'c': j = 3; break; case 'D': case 'd': j = 4; break;
                case 'E': case 'e': j = 5; break; case 'F': case 'f': j = 6; break; case 'G': case 'g': j = 7; break; case 'H': case 'h': j = 8; break;
                case 'I': case 'i': j = 9; break; case 'J': case 'j': j = 10; break; case 'K': case 'k': j = 11; break; case 'L': case 'l': j = 12; break;
                case 'M': case 'm': j = 13; break; case 'N': case 'n': j = 14; break; case 'O': case 'o': j = 15; break; case 'P': case 'p': j = 16; break;
            }
            if(j > 0 && j < 14)
            {
                i = returnMaxIndex(mainArray, j);
                cout << "The year of maximum energy production for " << types[j] << " is " << mainArray[i][0];
            }
            if(j == 14)
            {
                i = returnMaxIndex(fossilArray);
                cout << "The year of maximum energy production for fossil fuels is " << mainArray[i][0];
            }
            if(j == 15)
            {
                i = returnMaxIndex(renewableArray);
                cout << "The year of maximum energy production for renewable energy is " << mainArray[i][0];
            }
            if(j == 16)
            {
                i = returnMaxIndex(totalArray);
                cout << "The year of maximum energy production for total energy production is " << mainArray[i][0];
            }
        }
        break;

        case 'C': case 'c':
        break;

    }
}

int returnMaxIndex(double array[])
{
    double temp = array[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < 29; i++)
    {
        if(temp < array[i])
            temp = array[i];
    }
    cout << temp << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 29; i++)
    {
        if (temp == array[i])
            return i;
    }
}


int returnMaxIndex(double mainArray[][14], int j)
{
    int k = 0;
    double temp = labs(mainArray[k][j]);
    for(int i = 1; i < 29; i++)
    {
        if(temp < labs(mainArray[i][j]))
            temp = labs(mainArray[i][j]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 29; i++)
    {
        if (temp == labs(mainArray[i][j]))
            return i;
    }
}

void drawLine()
{
    cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
}
```

Contents of Energy.dat

```
1980  1161562368  245994189  346239900        0  251115575         0  276020970    275366    157797   5073079       0         0        0
1981  1203203232  206420775  345777173        0  272673503         0  260683544    245201    122628   5686163       0         0        0
1982  1192004204  146797490  305259749        0  282773248         0  309212893    195940    124979   4842865       0         0        0
1983  1259424279  144498593  274098458        0  293677119         0  332129735    215867    162745   6075101       0      2668        0
1984  1341680752  119807913  297393596        0  327633549         0  321150245    461411    424540   7740504    5248      6490        0
1985  1402128125  100202273  291945965        0  383690727         0  281149418    743294    639578   9325230   10630      5762        0
1986  1385831452  136584867  248508433        0  414038063         0  290844099    491509    685234  10307954   14032      4189        0
1987  1463781289  118492571  272620803        0  455270382         0  249694973    783088    693941  10775461   10497      3541        0
1988  1540652774  148899561  252800704        0  526973047         0  222939683    935986    738258  10300079    9094       871        0
1989  1562366197  159004961  297295127   454066  529354717         0  269189209   5582109   7742914  14593443  250601   2112043   282046
1990  1572108922  118863929  309486351   621112  576861678  -3507741  289753124   7032446  11499927  15434271  367087   2788600    11913
1991  1568845635  112798164  317773359   719074  612565087  -4541435  286019443   7735675  13853928  15966444  471765   2950951   402581
1992  1597713819   92237912  334274122  1212475  618776263  -4176582  250015684   8491095  15923885  16137962  399640   2887523   479806
1993  1665464154  105425325  342221829   966508  610291214  -4035572  277523663   9151852  16223338  16788565  462452   3005827   407651
1994  1666276091   98676618  385689325  1092023  640439832  -3377825  254004826   9232281  16983843  15535453  486622   3447109   239129
1995  1686056319   68145851  419178592  1926832  673402123  -2725131  305410435   7596774  17985777  13378258  496821   3164253   213275
1996  1771972991   74782864  378757294  1341140  674728546  -3088078  341158836   8386379  17816200  14328684  521205   3234069   201222
1997  1820761761   86479050  399595822  1533366  628644171  -4039905  350647962   8680229  18484565  14726102  511168   3288035    62807
1998  1850193304  122211090  449292578  2314896  673702104  -4467280  317866620   8608130  19233174  14773918  502473   3025696   158942
1999  1858617724  111539127  472995956  1606583  728254124  -6096899  314663058   8960705  19493050  14827013  495082   4487998   138942
2000  1943111290  105192123  517977999  2027956  753892940  -5538860  271337693   8916073  20307087  14093158  493375   5593261   124885
2001  1882826136  119148891  554939683   585791  768826308  -8823445  213749291   8293796  12944430  13740501  542755   6737332  6541565
2002  1910612813   89733266  607683246  1969851  780064087  -8742928  260491387   9009328  13145020  14491310  554831  10354279  9091465
2003  1952713826  113697198  567303392  2647093  763732695  -8535065  271511659   9527678  13807633  14424231  534001  11187467  8607470
2004  1957187710  114678307  627171620  3568233  788528387  -8488210  265063848   9736404  13061787  14810975  575155  14143741  8322440
2005  1992053878  116481854  683828924  3777156  781986365  -6557788  267039777  10569886  13031085  14691745  550294  17810549  6928168
2006  1969737146   59708237  734416872  4253528  787218636  -6557842  286253922  10341481  13927432  14568029  507706  26589137  7112762
2007  1998390297   61306315  814751904  4042131  806424753  -6896352  245842714  10711289  14294304  14637213  611793  34449927  6776960
2008  1976173298   42301486  798574077  3195712  806181935  -6238403  246100140  10901875  14872266  14859238  843054  52025898  6879905
```

Comment: Most probably you have hit some undefined behavior.

Comment: With 99.9999999999999% this is *not* an OS problem. (sigh)

Comment: A piece of unsolicited advice: if you're blaming your OS or compiler, you're probably wrong.

Comment: `I have asked my professor and he believed it to be an operating system problem`  You're joking, right?

Comment: `Which appears to be true`  No it isn't true.  The issue is that you have uninitialized variables.  A professor in C++ should have spotted this almost immediately.

Comment: I mean, I've been programming for 3 whole months now; I'm most definitely wrong. It's not like I'm coming here with a hello world program. Also, he's a mechanical engineer that got stuck with the class this semester, who has previously done most of his programming in Java. It's been a learning process for all of us to say the least.

Comment: Tip: `i = year - 1980` gets rid of some branching.

Comment: @expertninja Also, you should mention the *compiler* used, not the operating system.  There are several compilers for Windows (Visual Studio, g++, clang, etc.) and several different compiler brands for Linux (g++, clang, etc.).

Comment: @expertninja Unlike Java, C++ has a thing called `undefined behavior`.  That means that when you make mistakes like this, there is no telling how your program will run.

Comment: I did not record the specific implementation of c++ used, but I know that it doesn't have a lot of the c++ '11 implementation. It didn't work with Dev c++ and is working with Code:blocks in ubuntu. Thank you all for helping me hopefully knock out an A this semester.

Answer (score 3):

`fossilArray` seems not to be initialized before the `fossilArray[i] += mainArray[i][j];` line.

The same may hold for other arrays as well.

---

The problem is on this line:

```
double fossilArray[29];
```

The C++ standard doesn't guarantee that local variables are initialized. Visual Studio sets uninitialized local variables to some non-zero value to help locating this problem.

Comment: I was questioning whether this was a specific thing with the installed version of Dev C++ used in the school computers. I will initialize all of my arrays to zero and see if that changes anything, which I won't be able to check until I get back to school tomorrow morning. Thanks for all the help and negative votes.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you are using several arrays `fossilArray`, `renewableArray` and `totalArray` without ever initialising their values. They will not necessarily default to `0`, although they may be more likely to default to `0` in `Debug` and not `Release`. You can default intialise your arrays with the following:

```
double fossilArray[29] = {}; // construct all doubles with their default value (which is 0.0).
```